# Getting Response from telnet C# tcpclient

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I've been browsing for answers regarding my concern but I can't find concrete answers or at least clear thoughts on getting a response from Telnet connection. Here is my code:

```cs
TcpClient vpnMI = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 7505);
String message = "hold release\n";

Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
NetworkStream stream = vpnMI.GetStream();

stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Sent {0}", message);

data = new Byte[256];

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

String responseData = String.Empty;
Int32 bytes = 0;
do
{
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    memoryStream.Write(data, 0, bytes);                    
}
while (stream.DataAvailable);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

// Close everything.
stream.Close();
vpnMI.Close();
```

But I can only get the response before the "hold release" was sent even though there is a response after.
Thank you in advance for the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response @TheGeneral but what do you mean forever?? is it because of the `stream.DataAvailable` ?

Comment: If the server sends a lot of data `DataAvailable` will always be true. Telnet clients don't work that way. In the past, they sent to the console every byte received from the server immediatelly. A smarter approach is to read the output line by line. You can use a StreamReader for that. You can use a `StreamWriter` to write to the server without explicitly converting strings to bytes

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos I'm still somewhat not much good in this stuff so how does read the output line by line work? Should I set a loop that check if the line is != none?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this piece of code, you can take a look if this help:

```
public async Task<string> SendMessageAsync(string host, int port, string message, string encoding = "utf-8")
    {

        using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {
            //connect
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port);
            using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {

                //write message to stream
                var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding);
                var bytes = enc.GetBytes(message);
                await networkStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                //read response from stream
                var buffer = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //read all bytes to ms
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int byteCount = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);

                        if (byteCount < READ_BUFFER_SIZE)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //convert ms to string
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, enc))
                    {
                        var result = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

                        return result;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

networkStream.ReadAsync() returns the count of bytes that actually read from stream, if this count is less than the count you're trying to read, that's the last part.